# How to optimize clz count leading zeroes manual implementation?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have gathered from [around the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71936127/how-to-generate-lookup-table-for-counting-leading-zeroes-clzlut/71936202#71936202) a few functions and such to land on this:

```js
const LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE = makeLeadingZeroTable()

function makeLeadingZeroTable() {
  let i = 0
  const table = new Uint8Array(256)
  while (i < 256) {
    let count = 8
    let index = i
    while (index > 0) {
      index = (index / 2) | 0
      count--
    }
    table[i] = count
    i++
  }
  return table
}
// https://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/c-program-to-count-number-of-ones-in-unsigned-integer


function clz1(n)
{
  let accum = 0;

  accum += LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[n >> 24];
  accum += (accum == 8 ) ? LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[(n >> 16) & 0xFF] : 0;
  accum += (accum == 16) ? LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[(n >>  8) & 0xFF] : 0;
  accum += (accum == 24) ? LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[ n        & 0xFF] : 0;

  return accum;
}


function clz2(n)
{
  let accum = LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[n >> 24];

  if (accum === 8) {
    accum += LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[(n >> 16) & 0xFF]
  }
  if (accum === 16) {
    accum += LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[(n >>  8) & 0xFF]
  }
  if (accum === 24) {
    accum += LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[ n        & 0xFF]
  }

  return accum;
}

console.log('clz1', clz1(0b00100010001000100010001000100010))
console.log('clz1', clz1(0b00000010001000100010001000100010))

console.log('clz2', clz2(0b00100010001000100010001000100010))
console.log('clz2', clz2(0b00000010001000100010001000100010))
```

How do I transform `clz2` so it has the same output as `clz1`, but it does it in a more optimal way? I feel like the `+=` can be optimized away somehow? Is there a way to remove the conditional branching? Or is this as good as it's going to get?

*P.S. I know about the `clz32` and other related builtins, just doing this out of curiosity and for a custom programming language.*

I basically have this as of now, but would like to get rid of the conditional branching if possible.

```
function countLeadingZeroes32JS(n)
{
  let accum = LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[n >>> 24];

  if (accum === 8) {
    accum += LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[(n >>> 16)]
  }

  if (accum === 16) {
    accum += LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[(n >>>  8)]
  }

  if (accum === 24) {
    accum += LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[ n       ]
  }

  return accum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a hashmap instead? Have tested this with the given code and it looks like it works

````
const clz = new Map();

// Store a function in the hashmap, that performs the lookup
clz.set(8,  n => LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[ (n >> 16) & 0xFF]);
clz.set(16, n => LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[ (n >>  8) & 0xFF]);
clz.set(24, n => LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[ n & 0xFF]);

function clz3(n) {
    let accum = LEADING_ZERO_BIT_TABLE[n >> 24];

    // Without this, an error in the map lookup will crash this prog
    // might be worth revisiting error handling strategy... 
    try {
        // immediately invoke the expression stored inside the clz map, 
        // passing in 'n'
        accum += clz.get(accum)(n);
    } catch (e) {}

    return accum;
}
```
````

Comment: If this does work, a map will incur more processor steps (internally) than an if statement I think, was hoping for more bit-manipulation tricks if possible. But this is interesting, thank you.

Comment: I can't speak to the validity of that to be honest..  Another alternative I can suggest would be a switch statement. With a switch in lower level languages, a switch is usually better optimised by the compiler. I don't know enough about the internals of V8 to comment on whether the same is true for JS... food for thought :)

Comment: okay, on a bit of reading- the performance gain is likely negligible... a bit twiddling solution would certainly give you more here